# Are the PK and FK placed correctly in my ERD?

Tags: sql, erd

Just wanted to get feedback on my ERD. A bit rusty on my PK and FK. Scenario: An ice cream shop that orders flavored ice cream and keeps track of ingredients in each flavor. Customers can have many orders. Orders can have many flavors, and any flavor can have multiple ingredients. Thanks

[image: ERD Diagram]

Comment: So each flavor only has 1 ingredient? What about orders, can one order contain more than 1 flavor? Check your tables structure again after you answer those questions and see if your structure supports that.

Comment: If a flavour can have more than one ingredient, and assuming the same ingredient might be re-usable across flavours, then you'll need a link table between integredient and flavors, to implement a many-to-many relationship. But of course we don't know your actual requirements / constraints in the scenario - rather than assuming they're 100% clear to us, it's always better to actually state them, then we can compare them to what you've actually coded.

Comment: Responding to advice in comments:  I have updated the scenario in the question. thanks

Comment: Igor: So I need many to many for flavor-ingrendientz?

Comment: You still didn't make clear whether the same ingredient can be used in many flavours or not? But you'll certainly need many-to-many between orders and flavors, based on what you've now said (since it's hopefully self-evident that the same flavour can be re-used in many orders, and you've confirmed that an order can have many flavours).

Answer (score 0):

At the way the foreigns keys are, an order can ony have one flavor, and a flavor can only have one ingredient.
You need to create more 2 tables of n:m relationship: One table for the order flavors, and other for the flavor ingredients. Do a search about m to n relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The customers and orders are correctly related with a one-to-many relation:

- each `order` has one `customer_id`, and this FK  allows to find back the customer through the PK.
- since several `orders` can use the same `customer_id` (it's a FK), it's really a many orders possible for a single customer.

The ingredient to flavour relation is inconsistent.  According to the PK/FK, we can infer that  one ingredient (PK) could be used in many flavours (FK), but each flavour has only one ingredient_id, so can be associated only with one ingredient.  This is not what the connection between the two is telling.

To make flavours having multiple ingredients, you could add a FK `flavour_id` in `ingredients`.  Unfortunately, this would link an ingredient to a single flavour.  The only way out, would be to make this relation [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).  This requires an associative entity `flavour_ingredients` with a FK `flavour_id` and an FK `ingredient_id`  (you could add an id PK, or use a composite PK made of the two FKs)

The problem of the relation between `orders` and `flavours` is exactly the same.  The way you have modelled it is inconsistent, and you'd need a many-to-many relationship to model the reality of ice-cream orders.